# Configure WEBMIN for ProFTPD and Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, webmin, proftpd

I have a dedicated server running Webmin, Apache, ProFTP, PHP, MySQL,
ProFTP has been installed to use MySQL back-end.

Using FTP users can read files, but cannot CHMOD or WRITE to them.

There is a WordPress installation on one of the virtual hosts, and when the user attempts
to install a plugin using the FTP Details they are met with this error.

> Unpacking the package… Could not create directory.

Looks again like a user / group / permissions problem.

How do i best configure webmin's users and groups to allow a particular FTP user the
ability to read & write VIA ftp and to allow wordpress too .

Current USER:GROUP = ftpuser:www-data
Current FOLDER / FILE Permissions are : 0775

Comment: Do you know what the current directory and file permissions are set to?

Comment: That's the user:group...And what about the permissions?

Comment: all permissions were 0775